OmidSupported[false] is coming false when I am integrating OM SDK in Android App
When I am integrating OM SDK in android app according to the IAB integration DOC I am getting OMIDSUPPORTED as false, any idea here?
DOC link: https://interactiveadvertisingbureau.github.io/Open-Measurement-SDKAndroid/validation.html
I tried to every possible combinations still not able to omidSupported to true

Hi, could you share how you integrated the OM SDK, especially the initialization part?
